# While using Jena (java) or RDFLib (python), how should I find out whether to open the ontology as 'turtle' or 'xml'?

Tags: java, python, rdf, owl, ontology

Ontology files usually have extensions such as .owl or .rdf.

I want to know when I should open ontologies with 'turtle' and when with 'xml' or other formats? Because it seems that each of them is useful for a type of format and unfortunately, it seems that people sometimes save files with the wrong extension.

Here is a sample code in Python (but java is not very different either):

```
g.parse('ontology.owl', format='turtle')
```

So, how do I know here the turtle is the correct format?

Thanks in advance,
RF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening RDF files, not ontologies.

[RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) is an abstract data model. It has several [serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework#Serialization_formats):

1. [RDF/XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://example.com/ontology#"
     xml:base="http://example.com/ontology"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.com/ontology"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/ontology#Person"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/ontology#Woman">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://example.com/ontology#Person"/>
    </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

2. [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/):

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://example.com/ontology> a owl:Ontology .
<http://example.com/ontology#Person> a owl:Class .
<http://example.com/ontology#Woman>
    a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf <http://example.com/ontology#Person> .
```

3. [JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/):

```json
[ {
  "@id" : "http://example.com/ontology",
  "@type" : [ "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology" ]
}, {
  "@id" : "http://example.com/ontology#Person",
  "@type" : [ "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class" ]
}, {
  "@id" : "http://example.com/ontology#Woman",
  "@type" : [ "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class" ],
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf" : [ {
    "@id" : "http://example.com/ontology#Person"
  } ]
} ]
```

Open your file with a text editor, view what your file content looks similar to, and select approptiate option. You can use [this online service](http://www.easyrdf.org/converter) to convert RDF files from one serialization format to another.

RDF (abstract) syntax is not the only syntax for OWL ontologies. There are few others:

1. [OWL/XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-xml-serialization/):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://example.com/ontology"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     ontologyIRI="http://example.com/ontology">
    <Prefix name="" IRI="http://example.com/ontology#"/>
    <Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    <Prefix name="xml" IRI="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
    <Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#Person"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#Woman"/>
    </Declaration>
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#Woman"/>
        <Class IRI="#Person"/>
    </SubClassOf>
</Ontology>
```

2. [Functional syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/):

```
Prefix(:=<http://example.com/ontology#>)
Prefix(owl:=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>)
Prefix(rdf:=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
Prefix(xml:=<http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>)
Prefix(xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>)
Prefix(rdfs:=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>)

Ontology(<http://example.com/ontology>

Declaration(Class(:Person))
Declaration(Class(:Woman))

SubClassOf(:Woman :Person)
)
```

3. [Manchester syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/):

```
Prefix: : <http://example.com/ontology#>
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

Ontology: <http://example.com/ontology>

Class: Person

Class: Woman

SubClassOf: 
    Person
```

AFAIK, one can not parse files in these formats using RDFlib.
You can use [this online service](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/convert) to convert OWL files between these formats (and RDF formats).

Comment: I know I shouldn't thank you here, but since I have less than 15 reputations: thanks! :)