# Owl 2 DL parser tool

Tags: json, rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology

I'd like to know if exists any tool able to translate ontologies to OWL 2 DL. What I need is a converter able to take in input something like OWL, RDF, JSON, Manchester syntax etc etc... and convert it to OWL 2 DL format.

Comment: Well, OWL is an abstract syntax... It could be serialized into concrete syntaxes or into abstract RDF syntax (and then into concrete RDF syntaxes). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282563/7879193) contains more details (and in fact is just a paraphrase of https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/#Syntaxes).

Comment: But I saw a lot of tools on the web able to do similar translation, for instance "Manchester to RDF". I saw also a Java OWL API, I don't understand if it's possibe to build something thanks to it. What can you tell me about this?

Comment: Here is a command-line utility, based on OWL-API & Jena:  https://github.com/sszuev/ont-converter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OWL 2 DL` is not a format, as Stanislav mentioned. There are a number of defined formats to encode OWL 2 DL, many of which are only slightly different from the ones you mention - e.g., both OWL 1 and OWL 2 define a RDF serialization.

The `DL` bit refers to profile rules - an OWL 2 DL ontology needs all its classes and properties IRIs defined, for example (as opposed to OWL 2 Full or plain RDF).

OWL API can parse ontologies in a variety of formats, and, if the ontology is within the OWL 2 constraints, it can validate its profile. This will tell you whether an ontology conforms to the OWL 2 profile, and if not will give hints on what needs to change. See the OWL API wiki for examples on how to parse and save ontologies with it. https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused, that's why I apologize if I will tell something wrong. By the way, what I need is starting from the opposite point, let's say from RDF/TURTLE or whatever, and obtain a OWL 2 DL notation. I know that could seem weird, but this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again for your patience

Comment: The closer format to OWL 2 abstract syntax is Functional Syntax, among the output formats you have available in the OWL API. Or do you mean Description Logic notation, with mathematical symbols rather than keywords? That's also available but it's not OWL 2 DL, it's more general than any of the OWL languages.

Comment: I'm definitely agreeing with the second, with mathematical symbols. I'm referring to SROIQ(D) exactly. Is it really possible to obtain it? Thanks again!

Comment: Try using the DLSyntaxDocumentFormat with OWL API.